# Count the execution of an endpoint

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a table with different columns in postgres. One is named "count" and has as type number.
When there is a call on aspecific endpoint it should count + 1. Thus i will do a select to get the current count, do + 1 and put the new count into the table.

But its not working if the endpoint is called twice at the same time. Which solution would be possible? It should work like an auto increment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it on the DB side directly, in a single step.

```sql
UPDATE myTable
SET count = coalesce(count,0) + 1
WHERE ...;
```